# Is there a way to edit caption on Form Control buttons?

Tags: excel, vba, button

Is it possible (on a sheet change event), to change the caption text of a Form Control button?

Ideally, I would like to add a variable into the existing button caption depending on other data in the workbook.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, right click the Sheet1 tab on the bottom of spreadsheet and select view code

Copy paste the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Buttons("Button 1").Caption = "NEW TEXT"
End Sub
```

This event fires up when Sheet1 gets activated and it changes the caption on the button to `NEW TEXT`

Obviously you can refer to your buttons either by name or their index. You would to modify the `"Button 1"` if you want to modify the text on a different object.

You can assign it a variable or evaluation of an expression if you replace the `"NEW TEXT"`

For example

if on `Sheet2` you type anything in the cell A1 you can modify the code behind Sheet1 and use

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Buttons("Button 1").Caption = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

this way every time you activate Sheet1 the text on a button will be picked up from Sheet1, Cell A1

To find out the name of the button look here

[image]

Comment: I have multiple buttons on Sheet2.  How do I know which one is Button 1? I can't find the properties for the button.

Comment: Awesome!  That did it.  Didn't even realized that was hiding up there.  Was thinking I would of had to change all these to ActiveX buttons. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This works only for ActiveX controls not Form Controls.

Answer (score 5):

I needed **TextFrame.Characters.Text** to get to the caption

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("button 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Click"
```

Comment: Note for future readers: this is the solution for a "Form Control" button, the above accepted answer is for "ActiveX" type buttons.

Answer (score 3):

In this example Caption of Form-Control Button with name 'Button 1' is changed according to value of cell changed in 'Sheet1'. The button is on Sheet1, the code comes to Class-module of Sheet1. HTH

```
' Sheet1 module:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const buttonName As String = "Button 1"

    Dim targetButton As Excel.Button

    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetButton = Target.Worksheet.Buttons(buttonName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If targetButton Is Nothing Then _
        Exit Sub

    If Target.Value <> "" Then _
        targetButton.Caption = Target.Value

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").Select 
Selection.Characters.Text = "My New Caption"
```