# Text displayed on a button Excel Macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How do or is it possible to have a button assigned to a Macro and have the text of such button be a formula?

i.e

If A2 is "John Doe"

Can the button have John Doe as the text??? and If I change the name to "Jane Doe" have a formula (=A2) so that when Ichange the text the display text of the button change automatically???

Comment: This should help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578281/is-there-a-way-to-edit-caption-on-form-control-buttons

Comment: I use a rectangle shape as a button, you can select it and in formula bar type your formula `=A1`. this way we don't need any `Event`. we can assign a macro to this shape.

Comment: You can also use the cell and colour it grey to look like a button. Then you can use the event handlers for that cell to trap your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same has been answered through comments. However it has been marked as unanswered, hence answering behalf of **PKatona**

**Answer copied from**

**[Is there a way to edit caption on Form Control buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578281/is-there-a-way-to-edit-caption-on-form-control-buttons)**

**Answer 1**

Right click the Sheet1 tab on the bottom of spreadsheet and select view code

Copy paste the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Buttons("Button 1").Caption = "NEW TEXT"
End Sub
```

This event fires up when Sheet1 gets activated and it changes the caption on the button to NEW TEXT

Obviously you can refer to your buttons either by name or their index. You would to modify the "Button 1" if you want to modify the text on a different object.

You can assign it a variable or evaluation of an expression if you replace the "NEW TEXT"

For example

if on Sheet2 you type anything in the cell A1 you can modify the code behind Sheet1 and use

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Buttons("Button 1").Caption = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

this way every time you activate Sheet1 the text on a button will be picked up from Sheet1, Cell A1

To find out the name of the button look here

[image]